# Issue while adding dependency from local file system

Tags: eclipse, maven, nexus

Facing issue while adding dependency from local file system.

Am Using systemPath tag to locate dependency.

But jar files is there in the location mentioned.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.citi.166944:retail-basel-services:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.citi.163431:ets-ra-tools-aggregate-api:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/external_lib/ets-ra-tools-aggregate-api-1.0.3-JAVA7.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ com.citi.166944:retail-basel-services:[unknown-version], C:\Users\jj48521\eclipse-workspace\retail-basel-services-trunk\pom.xml, line 38, column 16
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.citi.163431:jrace-util:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/external_lib/jrace-util-1.17-basic-alpha-2.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ com.citi.166944:retail-basel-services:[unknown-version], C:\Users\jj48521\eclipse-workspace\retail-basel-services-trunk\pom.xml, line 232, column 16
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.citi.163431:jrace-params:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/external_lib/jrace-params-1.17-basic-alpha-2.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ com.citi.166944:retail-basel-services:[unknown-version], C:\Users\jj48521\eclipse-workspace\retail-basel-services-trunk\pom.xml, line 239, column 16
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin @ com.citi.166944:retail-basel-services:[unknown-version], C:\Users\jj\eclipse-workspace\retail-basel-services-trunk\pom.xml, line 266, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Retail Basel Services 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.3.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.456 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-08T12:00:28+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access citicore-plugins (http://sdfg.net:8081/nexus/content/repositories/citicore) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.3.1 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: The message `[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.3.1 is missin..` is more important cause it looks like you have network issues...

Comment: In debug mode got,

    "Could not transfer metadata com.citi.166944:retail-business-services:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to citi-artifactory (https://www.sgfd:443/artifactory/maven-teamdev): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Can i conclude from these error, "the issue is SSL certificate problem"

Comment: Yes you can. You should fix the SSL problem first...

Comment: Added the certificate of Nexus into the truststore of the Java running Eclipse:  https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465768-SSL-Certificate-Guide#java-client-trust-self-signed